Movie about a reporter trapped in the middle east
I was really exhausted at a Model UN conference and fell asleep watching this movie.  It was about this reporter woman who goes to write a story about a charismatic middle-eastern leader.  He won't let her see certain things and basically traps her in her room and says "you're free to leave -- good luck getting through the desert."  The leader is a sham dictator who uses Hollywood special effects people to make him look like a miracle-worker.  There's some guy who's like a prophet that people are all excited about, and he's also kidnapped by the leader guy.  The woman sneaks out of her room, and goes to the room where the dictator guy has all the battle plans, but the guy is coming up the stairs so she runs on the roof and falls in the cell of the prophet guy and then the dictator catches them, but they escape and are helped by some of the woman's reporter friends who come to rescue her and they fly off in an airplane.  I fell asleep after that.  It wasn't a very high-quality movie, kind of silly and goofily-acted, but I was curious if anyone knew what it was.

When did you see this movie?

It was on some TV station in the Boston hotel, Saturday night around 1 AM

The Jewel of the Nile

Joan Wilder (Kathleen Turner) is having trouble writing her next romantic novel while living with Jack Colton (Michael Douglas) on his boat, the Angelina, which is currently docked in a South of France port, and she refuses to discuss marriage. Later that afternoon at a book signing engagement held by her publisher, Gloria (Holland Taylor), Joan meets a charming Arab ruler named Omar (Spiros Focás) who has managed to persuade the world that he is the firm, but fair, ruler of Kadir. Omar offers Joan the opportunity to live like a queen at his palace, while she writes a fluff piece about him.
During her stay at his palace, Joan discovers that Omar is a brutal dictator, who imprisons her until she agrees to finish the fluff piece that will introduce him to the world as an enlightened ruler that will unite the Arab world. In the palace jail she meets a holy man, Al-Julhara (Arabic for 'The Jewel'), (Avner Eisenberg), who is in fact the Jewel of the Nile.

